# sync file and database drupal

Tags: drupal, centos, synchronization

i have 3 servers and install centos 5.5 ,drupal
now i want all server sync file and database

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this fully automatic:

1. Declare on server as master/source server. Any changes on the client machines are overwritten.
2. Use crontab to start the synchronization repeatedly on the client machines and to start drupal cron on the master machine.
3. Install ssh and install key files without pass phrase to get secure, reliable and unatended communication between the servers.
4. Use the backup and migrate module to get a MySql backup triggered by cron.
5. Do the file synchronization with rsync and keep an eye on file permissions to make sure files are accessible by the apache user on the destination servers.
6. Import the result of the backup and migrate backup into the client servers db.

A completely different approach would be to use the views module and create RSS Feeds of your nodes. The other servers could read and view them or update their data.

Again a different case: If you want to setup your 3 servers for load balancing / fail over purposes choose a distributed file system and a mirror setup for your db. This way the systems look like one big logical machine with the advantage that single physical machines can crash without crashing the whole system.